# Timeout error uploading 2 GIG file (resumable upload in Appengine task Python)

Tags: google-docs-api

I am getting a timeout error when trying to upload a 2 GIG file using resumable upload reurned from the Doclist api - please see log extract below. I thought using resumable upload in an Appengine task that 2 GIG would not be an issue, any ideas?

File "/base/data/home/apps/s~gofiledrop/31.358777816137338904/handler.py", line 564, in post
    new_entry = uploader.UploadFile('/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full?convert=false', entry=entry)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~gofiledrop/31.358777816137338904/gdata/client.py", line 1033, in upload_file
    start_byte, self.file_handle.read(self.chunk_size))
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~gofiledrop/31.358777816137338904/gdata/client.py", line 987, in upload_chunk
    desired_class=self.desired_class)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~gofiledrop/31.358777816137338904/gdata/client.py", line 265, in request
    uri=uri, auth_token=auth_token, http_request=http_request, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~gofiledrop/31.358777816137338904/atom/client.py", line 117, in request
    return self.http_client.request(http_request)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~gofiledrop/31.358777816137338904/atom/http_core.py", line 420, in request
    http_request.headers, http_request._body_parts)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~gofiledrop/31.358777816137338904/atom/http_core.py", line 497, in _http_request
    return connection.getresponse()
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/httplib.py", line 206, in getresponse
    deadline=self.timeout)